# Interpret ANOVA analysis of model fit IRT, TAM Package

Tags: model, item-response-theory

I posted this question on Stack Overflow, but was advised to post it here.

I fitted the same data set to a 1PL item response theory model (called `onePL` below), and then to a 2PL item response theory model (called `twoPL`) below.. Subsequently, I ran an ANOVA analysis to investigate which model had the best fit (using `anova(onePL, twoPL)`. I used the **TAM** package. Is anybody here familiar with interperting the output of such an ANOVA analysis? In the attached picture it looks like model 1 had a better fit, but surely, that's incorrect?

I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions.

| Model | loglike | Deviance | Npars | AIC | BIC | Chisq | df | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| onePL | 4499.997 | 8999.994 | 7 | 9013.994 | 9050.36 | 46.96485 | 5 | 0 |
| twoPL | 4476.514 | 8953.029 | 12 | 8977.029 | 9039.371 | NA | NA | NA |

Answer (score 0):

looks like your data has 6 items. In the `onePL` model you estimate 6 difficulty parameters and one variance parameter of the latent trait distribution, in total 7 parameters.

In the `twoPL` model you estimate 6 difficulty and 6 discrimination parameters (location and variance of the latent trait distribution is fixed), in total 12 parameters.

In the anova the test statistics is the differences between the deviances (which are $-2*log(likelihood)$; noted in the column `Deviance`). Note that the entries in the `loglike`-columns should be negative (check your results). The differences between the deviances is 46.965. Now check this against the $\chi^2$ distribution with 5 degrees of freedom (differences in the number of parameters; `df`). Using `1-pchisq(8999.994-8953.029, 5)` (which results in the `p` column value) can be interpreted as the probability that the differences in the model fit (i.e., deviances)  is due to chance, given 5 more parameters.

Note that `AIC` and `BIC` (lower is better) agree that the 5 additional parameters help improving the model fit.

Comment: Dear @Tom, many thanks for your answer! It certainly clarifies things. I guess I was confused by the layout of the table - to me it looked like the `onePL` was significantly better given that the p-value was reported on that line. (In the original output the _loglike_ values were indeed negative (a copy error of mine). Again: thanks!